# Diesel "get_results" gives a trait bound error

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to make an Actix API with Diesel, and in making the first endpoint (/books/create), I am having trouble trying to get the inserted value back into my code.

This is my insert:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use crate::models::Book;
use crate::schema::books;
use crate::db;


pub fn create_book(book: &Book) -> Book {
    
    let mut connection: SqliteConnection = db::establish_connection();
    let result: QueryResult<Book> = diesel::insert_into(books::table)
        .values([book])
        .get_result::<Book>(&mut connection);
        
    
    result.unwrap()
}
```

This is the error, which I wrapped in a pastebin since it's too long for Stackoverflow: https://pastebin.com/Evq6tUYq

I wonder if it can be a problem of the schema or model, but they seem to be okay'ish and don't have mismatching values, as far as I know:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};    
use crate::schema::books;

#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize, Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = books)]
pub struct Book {
    pub id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub author: String,
    pub creation_date: Option<String>,
    pub publishing_house: Option<String>,
    pub release_date: Option<String>,
    pub cover_image: Option<String>
}



diesel::table! {
    books (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        title -> Text,
        author -> Text,
        publishing_house -> Nullable<Text>,
        release_date -> Nullable<Text>,
        cover_image -> Nullable<Text>,
        creation_date -> Nullable<Text>,
    }
}
```

Where is the error? What's missing?

Comment: I can't verify, but can you try replacing `.values([book])` with just `.values(book)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to answer this question as it is missing important details like the used diesel version, and the enabled feature flags for diesel.

The underlying problem is that `.get_result()` uses `INSERT INTO … RETURNING` SQL statements internally. These are only supported by Sqlite 3.35 or newer. As of this support for such statements is behind a separate diesel feature flag. You need to enable the  `returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35` feature flag.

That by itself will not fix the issue. `.values([book])` creates a array with one element and tries to insert that. This will cause diesel to use a batch insert statement, which normally allows to insert more than one element at once. While this is supported for the sqlite backend it cannot be used in combination with the returning support described above, as SQLite is missing another SQL feature here (using the `DEFAULT` keyword to signal that a certain value should be replaced by the corresponding database default value). In your case this can be fixed by just calling `.values(&book)`, which constructs an ordinary single row insert.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd edit your answer and add how feature flags can be enabled, since it took me a while to know how to add it. After a while, I managed to do it and, as you said, it works fine when just adding a single value. Thank you!

Comment: The `cargo.toml` file is the location where you set this flag, like so for example: `diesel = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["sqlite", "returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35"] }`

Answer (score -2):

You cant use Queryable and Insertable trait in the same Book struct you must separate them into 2 different structs.

```
#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Book {
  pub id: i32,
  pub title: String,
  pub author: String,
  pub creation_date: Option<String>,
  pub publishing_house: Option<String>,
  pub release_date: Option<String>,
  pub cover_image: Option<String>
}


#[derive(Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = books)]
pub struct BookInsert {
  pub id: i32,
  pub title: String,
  pub author: String,
  pub creation_date: Option<String>,
  pub publishing_house: Option<String>,
  pub release_date: Option<String>,
  pub cover_image: Option<String>
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. `Queryable` and `Insertable` can be used by the same struct.

Comment: When implementing Insertable, you probably won't be setting the auto-incremented id field of the row. Usually you will also ignore fields such as created_at and updated_at. For this reason, it's not advisable to use Queryable and Insertable on the same struct due to the field number constraints of Queryable. Create another struct that you may use for database insertions that will have all the fields you would like to set.

Comment: This section will not cover nullable fields (we'll cover that in AsChangeset), so we will assume every field must have data in our example. When making a separate struct for database inserts, Diesel needs to know the corresponding table name, so the struct must also be annotated with the #[table_name="some_table_name"] attribute. If your new struct has different field names, each of them may be annotated with #[column_name(some_column_name)].

Comment: That's all fine and correct, at least up to a certain point. Nevertheless it's not the case that you **cannot** use both on the same struct nor that this is the issue in the question. I'm sorry your answer is just not correct for this question.